# Кака функция в vk-io отвечает за ID человека в пересыльном сообщении?

Tags: javascript, node.js, вконтакте

Не могу найти функцию в библиотеке [vk-io](https://github.com/negezor/vk-io), которая отвечает за ID того человека, кто находится в пересыльном сообщении:

[image: нужно смотреть верхние сообщение]

Нашел я только функцию, которая отвечает за получение ID пользователя, который отправил ЭТО сообщение.

Язык: node js.

Answer (score 0):

Если еще нужно:

```
message.replyMessage.senderId
```